# Not countable generated sigma field

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I need to show that $ F=(A \in \Omega $| A countable or co-countable) with $\Omega$=(0,1] is not countable generated. I have started supposing that F is countable generated and I have a hont that tell me to proove that then F is generated by a countable set of singletons.

I dont understand why this step is not direct

then Im told to see that F must consist of the sets $B$ and $B\cup \Omega^{c}_{0}$ with $B \in \Omega_{0}$ and $\Omega_{0}$ the union of these singletons. I can´t understand why this step is enough to prove the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singletons look to me like an unnecessary detour. If $F$ were generated by countably many of its elements, then it would also be generated by a family $G$ of countably many countable sets, because you could just replace any co-countable sets among the original generators by their complements.  The union $U$ of all the generators in $G$ is a countable set, so you can let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct elements of $\Omega-U$.  Now the set
$$
M=\{X\subseteq\Omega:x\in X\iff y\in X\}
$$
contains all the generators in $G$ (because these contain neither $x$ nor $y$) and is closed under complementation and union. So it includes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $G$, namely $F$.  But that is absurd, as there are certainly countable sets not in $M$, for example $\{x\}$.